# Паттерн Репозиторий: Singleton или нет?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, антипаттерн

помогите пожалуйста разобраться паттерн Репозиторий должен быть Singletonом или нет? и почему?

паттерн Репозиторий - хранилище коллекции объектов. хранилище как я понимаю должно быть одно, значит репозиторий должен быть Singleton, однако на просторах интернета такое редко встречается

обоснование: не можем подменить реализацию - при работе с другим хранилищем мы не будем имплементить интерфейс репозиторий, а будем наследоваться от реализованного класса репозитория?

Comment: Так то используется IoC контейнер, где паттерн синглтона не нужен - синглтованность инстансов и подмену реализаций обеспечивает сам контейнер.

Comment: Извините, мне кажется, что IoC контейнер обеспечивает только подмену реализации. А сингловость он каким образом реализует?